# Table-Table Join duplicate entries

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

we are using kafka in production and I try to push the adoption and usage of KSQL in the same direction. But I already failed with one simple table-table join. I’ve tried with our production data first and ran in an issue. So I thought I missed something and moved back to the example from the confluent docs and ran in the same problem.
I will explain my issue with the example data https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/basics-docker.html#table-table-join
When I have created both tables and try to join the data it works, but as soon as I try to alter or add something I get new entries in my table. From every example I found at confluent or even at the youtube videos this is not suppose to happen.

Creating records

```
docker run --interactive --rm --network tutorials_default \
  confluentinc/cp-kafkacat \
  kafkacat -b kafka:39092 \
          -t warehouse_location \
          -K: \
          -P <<EOF
1:{"warehouse_id":1,"city":"Leeds","country":"UK"}
2:{"warehouse_id":2,"city":"Sheffield","country":"UK"}
3:{"warehouse_id":3,"city":"Berlin","country":"Germany"}
EOF
```

```
docker run --interactive --rm --network tutorials_default \
  confluentinc/cp-kafkacat \
  kafkacat -b kafka:39092 \
          -t warehouse_size \
          -K: \
          -P <<EOF
1:{"warehouse_id":1,"square_footage":16000}
2:{"warehouse_id":2,"square_footage":42000}
3:{"warehouse_id":3,"square_footage":94000}
EOF
```

Creating tables

```
CREATE TABLE WAREHOUSE_LOCATION (WAREHOUSE_ID INT, CITY VARCHAR, COUNTRY VARCHAR)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='warehouse_location',
      VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
      KEY='WAREHOUSE_ID');

CREATE TABLE WAREHOUSE_SIZE (WAREHOUSE_ID INT, SQUARE_FOOTAGE DOUBLE)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='warehouse_size',
      VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
      KEY='WAREHOUSE_ID');
```

Creating a joined table:

```
CREATE TABLE WH_U AS SELECT WL.WAREHOUSE_ID, WL.CITY, WL.COUNTRY, WS.SQUARE_FOOTAGE
FROM WAREHOUSE_LOCATION WL
  LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE_SIZE WS
    ON WL.WAREHOUSE_ID=WS.WAREHOUSE_ID;
```

With this I get the expected results:

```
1 | Leeds | UK | 16000.0
2 | Sheffield | UK | 42000.0
3 | Berlin | Germany | 94000.0
```

But when I add or chnage records, this happens:

```
1566375174496 | 1 | 1 | Leeds | UK | 16000.0
1566375174496 | 2 | 2 | Sheffield | UK | 42000.0
1566375174496 | 3 | 3 | Berlin | Germany | 94000.0
1566375595372 | 4 | 4 | London | UK | null
1566375641291 | 4 | 4 | London | UK | 94000.0
1566375641291 | 1 | 1 | Leeds | UK | 1.0
```

I expected:

```
1566375174496 | 1 | 1 | Leeds | UK | 1.0
1566375174496 | 2 | 2 | Sheffield | UK | 42000.0
1566375174496 | 3 | 3 | Berlin | Germany | 94000.0
1566375641291 | 4 | 4 | London | UK | 94000.0
```

What am I missing?

**SOLVED**

The reason for this behaviour was a simple env in ksql server. KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING was set to 0

Comment: how did you add records? `1566375595372 | 4 | 4 | London | UK | null`
 means does not join with the other ktable

Comment: I added the new records with kafkacat

kafkacat -P -b 127.0.0.1:29092 -t warehouse_size -K:
4:{"warehouse_id":4,"square_footage":94000}

kafkacat -P -b 127.0.0.1:29092 -t warehouse_location -K:
4:{"warehouse_id":4,"city":"London","country":"UK"}

The thins is, he joined but with the showed me with the select twice the entries with ID 4. I expected the same results as you can find in the live demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eMXWeBfK7U

Comment: You should create an answer for your question, and then mark your own answer as 'Accepted'.